# Go dep list dependencies links

Tags: go, dependencies, dep

Is it possible to list just links/names to go dependencies? 
For example in `Gopkg.lock` I have:

```
[[projects]]
  digest = "x:xxxxxxx"
  name = "cloud.google.com/go"
  packages = [
    "xxxxx",
    "xxxxx/xxxxx",
  ]
```

I want just `name`: cloud.google.com/go be listed

Comment: `go list` just list the name of the current project. but actually i need a list of external dependencies

Comment: ```dep``` can't do it out of box. The easiest way is creating your own tool to parse Gopkg.lock. It shouldn't take more than half an hour.

Comment: Sorry, missed the `dep` part (though `go list` can list imports, or all dependencies, test imports, files etc). Since `cloud.google.com/go` is a package just like any other, I would also just parse your lock file for the information you want.

Comment: @bayrinat thanks, went that way